# Android: Why onTouchListener() opens multiple Alert Dialog?

Tags: android, android-spinner, ontouchlistener

I want to open an alert dialog containing Autocomplete TextView when I click spinner. here's code

```
resNonRes = (Spinner)activity.findViewById(componentNameIdMap.get("SPINNER"));
resNonRes.setOnTouchListener(touch);

OnTouchListener touch = new OnTouchListener(){
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        final AutoCompleteTextView av = new AutoCompleteTextView(activity);
        av.setAdapter((ArrayAdapter)resNonRes.getAdapter());
        AlertDialog.Builder builderSingle  = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
        builderSingle.setTitle("Exception");
        builderSingle.setView(av);
        builderSingle.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                String avv = av.getText().toString();
                ArrayAdapter myAdap = (ArrayAdapter) resNonRes.getAdapter(); //cast to an ArrayAdapter
                int spinnerPosition = myAdap.getPosition(avv); //set the default according to value
                resNonRes.setSelection(spinnerPosition);
              }
            });
        builderSingle.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
              public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                  // Canceled.
              }
            });
        builderSingle.show();
        return false;
    }
};
```

But it opens more than one alert dialogs.

**I can not use onclick listeners as spinner does not support item click events neither I can use onItemSelectedSpinner because of contraints in my project as I am using it as general for all spinners.**

Please Suggest...

Comment: because it raise on more than one event, like 'Down,Up,...', u should check your desire event and write your own function inside it.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're doing it for all touch events-  ups, down, moves, etc.  You should only do it on up.